# Navigator language is not getting change

Tags: navigator

I changed the language settings from english to Chinese in Chrome browser. But navigator.language is still displaying as 'en-US'. Expected output should be 'zh'.
Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to change the language setting in two places.

If you're seeing Chrome menus and words in the wrong language, please follow the steps to change Chrome's default language: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95416?hl=en

If you're seeing all Google products in the wrong language, please go here to update your language settings: https://www.google.com/settings/account